# If else ladder using Case in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write if elif ladder in SQL but I am finding it little difficult to do that. My ladder looks like below.

```
IF (MortgageProduct.FreeLegalFees != NULL) THEN
      IF(MortgageProduct.FreeLegalFees==1) THEN
         Return TRUE as FreeLegalFees
      ELSE 
         Return FALSE as FreeLegalFees
ELSE    
      IF (ConveyancerFee!=NULL) THEN
          IF ConveyancerFee.AMOUNT = 0.0 then
             Return TRUE as FreeLegalFees
          ELSE
             Return FALSE as FreeLegalFees
      END IF
ELSE      
     IF (LenderFee!=NULL) THEN
        IF LenderFee.AMOUNT = 0.0 then
           Return TRUE as FreeLegalFees
        ELSE
           Return FALSE as FreeLegalFees
     END IF
ELSE 
     Return TRUE as FreeLegalFees
END IF
```

I know that I have to use Case for that in SQL but I am confuse in writing Case statement in sql. Can somebody please help me to frame this ladder in sql server.

Comment: is this part of a select statement? are you just tryint to "see" information? or are you insided a function that returns something? what does the 'as' do in this case?

Comment: Your statement is a little confusing. You have `IF (ConveyancerFee!=NULL) ` and then reference `ConveyancerFee.AMOUNT `.  Should they be the same?

Comment: You do not need explicit `NULL` checks if you're checking for a value, so a check like `A != NULL AND A == 1` can be simplified to `A == 1`. Note also that T-SQL has no boolean type, so you can't actually return or assign true or false. The best you can do is a `BIT` -- but note that in T-SQL it's often "wrong" to calculate a bit and then use it later, as that can't be optimized; instead the logical expression needs to be folded into the query and acted on directly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I initially thought the same, however, the OP checks for `NULL` and then a specific value. If it isn't the specific value `0` is returned. If, however, all the checked columns have a value of `NULL` then `1` is returned. (talking in `bit` here rather than `TRUE`/`FALSE`)

Comment: @Larnu: it may be bad of me to do so, but I didn't assume the OP's logical expression was completely correct. I just though it prudent to mention that checks for `NULL` are often redundant. Whether that helps in this case is another matter. :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert That i do agree with. :) On the logic we have, however, does seem that it would be needed.

Comment: One more thing: if this logic *is* correct, and stands to be more complicated later, strongly consider folding this into computed columns or use `CHECK` constraints and `NOT NULL` columns with default values to simplify things. T-SQL is a bad language to have to write (and read) business logic in, so any opportunity you can take to avoid it pays off. For example, is `FreeLegalFees` a `BIT` column? If it is, is there any reason it allows `NULL` and does not enforce either yes or no as a default?

Comment: Hello All. Thank you very much all for your valuable input's. I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is far more succinct. I have also aliased what I assume are your table names:

```
CASE WHEN MP.FreeLegalFees IS NOT NULL THEN IIF(MP.FreeLegalFees = 1,1,0)
     WHEN CF.AMOUNT IS NOT NULL THEN IIF(CF.AMOUNT = 0,1,0)
     WHEN LF.Amount IS NOT NULL THEN IIF(LF.AMOUNT = 0,1,0)
     ELSE 1 END
/*
MP MortgageProduct
CF ConveyancerFee
LF LenderFee
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
(case when mp.FreeLegalFees = 1 then 1
      when mp.FreeLegalFees is not null then 0 
      when cf.amount = 0.0 then 1
      when cf.amount is not null then 0
      when lf.amount = 0.0 then 1
      when lf.amount is not null then 0
      else 1
  end) as FreeLegalFees
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 CASE 
            WHEN MP.FREELEGALFEES = 1 THEN 1
            WHEN MP.CONVEYANCERLEGALFEESET IS NOT NULL THEN 
                 ( 
                   CASE 
                        WHEN ( 
                              (SELECT AMOUNT FROM CONVEYANCERLEGALFEE WHERE LOCATION=@p_iLocation 
                              and TYPEOFAPPLICATION=@p_iTypeOfApplication 
                              and TYPEOFBUYER=@p_iTypeOfBuyer and MAXIMUMVALUE=100000 
                              and CONVEYANCERLEGALFEESETSTRTDATE <= (SELECT GETDATE()) 
                              and CONVEYANCERLEGALFEESET = MP.CONVEYANCERLEGALFEESET ) = 0.0) 
                              THEN 1
                        ELSE 0 
                    END
                  )
            WHEN ((Select COUNT(FEESET) FROM LEGALFEE WHERE TYPEOFAPPLICATION=@p_iTypeOfApplication 
                  AND FEETYPE = (Select VALUEID from COMBOVALUE where VALUENAME='Redeeming')) >= 1 ) THEN
                  (
                     CASE
                          WHEN (
                                (SELECT AMOUNT FROM LEGALFEE 
                                  WHERE TYPEOFAPPLICATION = @p_iTypeOfApplication 
                                  AND FEETYPE= (SELECT VALUEID FROM COMBOVALUE WHERE VALUENAME='Redeeming')) = 0.0) 
                                  THEN 1
                          ELSE 0
                     END
                  )
              ELSE 1
```

This is the solution which works perfect. Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

```
CASE 
        WHEN MortgageProduct.FreeLegalFees IS NOT NULL
            THEN (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN MortgageProduct.FreeLegalFees = 1
                            THEN 'TRUE'
                        ELSE 'FALSE'
                        END
                    )
        WHEN ConveyancerFee  IS NOT NULL
            THEN (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN ConveyancerFee.AMOUNT = 0.0
                            THEN 'TRUE'
                        ELSE 'FALSE'
                        END
                    )
        WHEN LenderFee  IS NOT NULL
            THEN (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN LenderFee.AMOUNT = 0.0
                            THEN 'TRUE'
                        ELSE 'FALSE'
                        END
                    )
        ELSE 'TRUE'
        END AS FreeLegalFees
```

Comment: `!= NULL` will always evaluate to `unknown`, so that expression will always evaluation to `'TRUE'`.